# Jmeter POST API issue

Tags: java, rest, csv, post, jmeter

There is a *JAVA REST API* (**Put** request) that I want to hit with values from a CSV file.

The CSV file is:

[image]

The JMETER CSV configuration is:

[image]

This is how I have set up the JMETER Configuration to hit the API:

[image]

The deserialisation on the Java side is not happening correctly. From POSTMAN, the following works:

```
{
  "productId": "ABC",
  "score": 4.42489
}
```

Why is the Jmeter POST configuration not working correctly?

**Error: Received Unknown exception com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of double from String value '$score': not a valid Double value**

**Update**: On doing this in Jmeter configuration:

```
{
    "productId" : "${product}",
    "score": "${score}"
}
```

I got the following error:

**Received Unknown exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4063ce7d; line: 2, column: 18] Similarly for M, M and R. So 4 errors in total.**

**Update 2**:[*Solved*]The following CSV Data Set Configuration worked without any change in the actual CSV file!!

[image]

A Big Thank you to @user7294900 for the help!!

Comment: Shouldn't you use `delimiter` as `,` instead of `/n` as your CSV file shows that data is comma separated?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot curly braces (this is not velocity/postman)

You need to send HTTP Request Body Data:

```
{
    "productId": "${product}",
    "score": "${score}"
}
```

Check the [maunual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for more details:

> Variables are referenced as follows:
>
> ${VARIABLE}

Also your quotes in CSV file is redundant, either change `Allow quoted data` to `true` or better yet remove all quotes `"` from CSV file.

Comment: Getting a different error: **Received Unknown exception com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4063ce7d; line: 2, column: 18]** Similarly for M, M and R. So 4 errors in total. Why?

Comment: did you changed to productId as in postman? "productId": "${product}",

Comment: Also change `Allow quoted data` to `true` or better yet remove all quotes `"` from CSV file

Answer (score 1):

i do wonder if you might also have a problem with product_id being the parameter name versus productID that works directly in postman.

Comment: :-) no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotation marks around "${product}" and **${score}** as:

1. Your CSV file already has quotations around ProductId I don't think you need duplicate ones
2. Your application expects a [**Double**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and you are basically sending a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

So change your payload to look like:

```
{
    "productId" : ${product},
    "score": ${score}
}
```

More information:

- [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)
- [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)